# How to understand if there was an Integer overflow during parsing of string with Kotlin?

Tags: string, algorithm, kotlin, parsing, integer

In Java architects of the language used prefixes like `L/l` for long numbers to make parsing easier and to differentiate Int vs Long constants. I am making a deserialisation library for TOML and received a [request](https://github.com/akuleshov7/ktoml/issues/163) from the user not only to support easy-parsing to Long, but also to Int numbers depending on the string input.

So during the parsing I need to understand if the string in the input is Byte/Short/Int or Long and select a proper type automatically for an input.

This leads me to a question: is there any library **in Kotlin** (my library is MPP) that can help me to check if ? Like `Math` does it in Java. I am pretty sure that there should be some obvious library or algorithm for it, so I do not want to implement my yet another one.

If you will propose not a library, but a good algorithm for determine a type of an integer number by the string input - that will also be fine for me. But better it would be some known-algorithm.

We should not also forget about UNSIGNED int that are there in Kotlin but missing in Java

Comment: Which functionality of Java do you mean exactly? I don't think `Math` provides anything like this. Do you mean parsing of literals by the compiler?

Comment: Deraialize to Long. Then `val canConvertToInt = value in Int.MIN_VALUE..Int.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: How is ktoml parsing numbers currently? Have investigated how Kotlinx Serialization handles these cases for JSON?

Comment: It would be very strange and surprising to not return the same type every time, unless the user can specify which type they want.  Giving the user a value of an unknown number type is rarely a useful or good idea, and it's quite possible you should just tell that user no.

Comment: @Tenfour04 you are forgetting that Kotlin has Unsigned Long. This will not work in this way. But that should work with changing toml specification in ktoml a littlest and adding 'u' to the unsigned literals

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the positive part of an integer. If your integer is larger, than Int.MAX_VALUE it becomes negative. So when it becomes negative, you know there is an overflow.

```
Int.MAX_VALUE + 1 // produces a negative value
```

You can also try this library for parsing. https://github.com/tiksem/KotlinSpirit

```
val errorCode = int.compile().parseWithResult("3453534435543543345345").errorCode
```

errorCode will be `ParseCode.INT_OUT_OF_BOUNDS`